# AWS Amplify Auth - Social Login

Tags: android, swift, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I have an app both in Android and iOS platform and I have a different back-end lambdas based on Node.js.

I want to add social login in app -> When user clicks "Sign In With Google" or "Sign In With Apple". I need to exchange these credentials to AWS Cognito credentials (ID token) to give access to other resources.

I have achieved this by using Hosted UI -> So In my NodeJs Lambda, I create a URL with temporary state and send to the apps.

But user needs to click twice -> First button in app, then app opens with URL of web page and needs to click again with same button.

I need to achieve this without opening the web page.

Do you have any suggestions or ways to fix this?

Regards,